# Make a copy of an aspx page without Ambiguity errors

Tags: asp.net, ambiguity

I need to create a public version of an .aspx page within the same project, with just a few minor modifications. My boss just wants the ability to have a link to the new public version of the page. Whenever I create a copy of that page and the reports it connects too though, I just get a lot of Ambiguity Errors. Is there a way to avoid this?
I was thinking of trying to change the namespace of all the documents within it, but so far it's just been producing more errors.

The other option would be to go through and change each individual variable by hand, but there are around 12 different documents each with an aspx page and cs page that would need to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of the code-behind class. For example, from:

```
public class SomePage : Page {
```

To:

```
public class SomePagePublic : Page {
```

Comment: I had tried that before, and it wasn't working, I think because the pages were within the same namespace

Comment: What error you receive when changing the name of the class? "wasn't working" is not enough information :)

Comment: I receive ambiguity errors on the variable names withing the classes, the names of the classes weren't explicitly a problem. The error reads "Ambiguity on " and lists the two files that have similar variable names, sorry for lack of information

Comment: Ok, if classes are different, there shouldn't generate ambiguity errors. Please provide the code you are using.